# Style live text in a input form

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to style the text the is being typed into a form. I.e. change color and font as it is being typed. Note: not the placeholder text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can dynamically apply style to input

```js
window.onload = main;


function main() {

const el = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(el)
el.addEventListener('input', onChange);
}

function onChange(e) {
let text = e.target.value;

let colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan'];

e.target.style.color = colors[text.length % 5];
}
```

```css
h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
padding: 5px;
font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<h2> type in input to see the effect</h1>

<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Having some problems getting to work on all the input tags, can only get to work on one at a time, in example below works on the first one but not the second one. if i however remove the first test id, it works on the second one.

 `<label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input autofocus required type="text" id="test" id="fname" name="firstname" /><br>
  <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input required type="text" id="test" id="lname" name="lastname" /><br> `

Comment: `id` should be unique.. learn / google about how to attach event listeners to multiple elements

Comment: NM, i would use the getElementByClass, still new JS

Comment: write some code and share it with me on jsbin or something .. i will take a look

Comment: no , that is not how you attach event listeners to multiple elements, i told you to read about it

Comment: ok i read up on it, made some changes, it has mistakes, but am i going in the right direction here, still new to js  https://jsbin.com/qofumagele/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: do one step at a time.. attach event listener to multiple elements and make it work